# using dynamic values in src

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm writing a media player for my android application using angularjs, I get the songs from web API, address: http://10.96.254.34:8885/api/apimusic/download?songId=X, with "X" is the id of the song I want to stream.  You can try add "1", "2" or "3" at "X" to listen to the song.
My problem is, when I use write the code for the audio player:

```
<div class="item item-thumbnail-left">
          <h2>{{song.SongName}}</h2>
          <p>{{song.Singer}}</p>

       <audio id="audio" autoplay="true" preload="auto" tabindex="0" controls="" type="audio/mpeg">
          <source type="audio/mpeg" src="http://10.96.254.34:8885/api/apimusic/download?songId=1">
          Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
       </audio>
          </div>
```

The song can be fetched flawlessly, but when I change it to:
http://10.96.254.34:8885/api/apimusic/download?songId={{song.SongId}}, It doesn't work

Any ideas to help me out of this? Please help :(

Comment: use ng-src instead of src

Answer (score 2):

Try to use in source:

```
data-ng-src
```

or

```
ng-src
```

instead of using a simple `src`.

Answer (score 2):

Its because of Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE), which is by default enabled in Angularjs.

passing expression to url inside href or src is not allowed, so instead prepare your url with expression and then assign it to src. for ex:

Instead of

```
ng-src="http://yourdomain.com/a={{id}}"
```

do

```
in Controller:
    $scope.url = "http://yourdomain.com/a="+$scope.id;
in View
    ng-src="{{url}}"
```

And make sure of CORS issue as well. If you are calling audio url from different domain.

Comment: what error you are getting, please check in console and post it